# backup github repo with client access token

Tags: github, github-api

we have a customer that wants us to backup his private github repo. He wants us to use a client access token with read only access.

Is this feasible? is it possible to do this on a regular basis with the same token? Any recommendation on the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Evan

Comment: You might also consider using read-only deploy keys for this. Ref: [read-only deploy keys](https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys)